# Why is a Gruyère sweet when it contains 0 carbohydrates?

Tags: cheese, sugar

I have read on packaging that a Gruyère appears to be around 0 g, maybe 0.4 g carbohydrates per 100g. How come it tastes sweet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cheese is a complex variety of chemical compounds some of which can taste sweet. I don't know the exact make up of Gruyère but according to [this article](https://eic.rsc.org/feature/really-cheesy-chemistry/2020218.article) there are a couple of compounds that are known to lend a sweet flavor. Including: butyric acid, Alanine, glycine, serine, threonine, ethanol, etc.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruy%C3%A8re_cheese) says that Gruyère is a "sweet" cheese so I would assume these compounds mentioned above are in higher amounts than other cheeses.

Comment: Makes sense. It could be the *furaneol* or the *butyric acid*.

Comment: Butyric acid could certainly bring the sour/pungent element that we associate with something being CLOYINGLY sweet. Ethanol? Ironically, it isn't sweet but chemically not that far from a sugar.

Comment: I'm only quoting the article. As a person in the wine industry for decades ethanol does have a sweet component and this peer reviewed article backs me up https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10940547

Comment: Ethanol is certainly sweet and fruity.